# How to see if a slurm job actually runs using the specified number of cores

Tags: monitoring, jobs, slurm

I am running a job that supposedly uses OMP threading with 16 cores. I think something is wrong, so I am trying to monitor it while running. I ssh to the node, and use top to get the following:

[image]

Does this look right? It seems it means only 1 CPU is used at 1600% capacity instead of 16 at 100%

Answer (score 0):

Use top with the -H flag

> -H  :Threads-mode operation
>               Instructs top to display individual threads.  Without this
>               command-line option a summation of all threads in each process
>               is shown.  Later this can be changed with the `H' interactive
>               command.